# Excel VBA - Split one row data in mutiple rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to take an excel file, look at the columns which have been filled and then split data in one excel row into various rows and in the process eliminate certain columns using VB. I think it will make more sense if you look at the images below.

Below is the image of what I am trying to split.

[image: Before]

Below is the image of how I want it split.

[image: After]

If someone can help me with it's VB code that would be great. I am new to VB and trying to learn.

Comment: Have you already attempted to write a piece of code that you could share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following code:

```
Sub Format()

lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For x = lastrow To 2 Step -1

    If Range("G" & x).Value <> "" Then
        Rows(x + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range("A" & x + 1 & ":D" & x + 1).Value = Range("A" & x & ":D" & x).Value
        Range("E" & x + 1).Value = Range("G" & x).Value
        Range("G" & x).Value = ""
    End If

    If Range("F" & x).Value <> "" Then
        Rows(x + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range("A" & x + 1 & ":D" & x + 1).Value = Range("A" & x & ":D" & x).Value
        Range("E" & x + 1).Value = Range("F" & x).Value
        Range("F" & x).Value = ""
    End If

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. Appreciate it. I added code to delete the columns F and G so that there are no headers left when code is run.

Comment: @Gary No worries, glad to help. You can also just do do Range("F1:G1").Value = "" to clear the headers.